# Show error page when application crash because of unhandled exception

Tags: android, exception

I want to start an activity when my application crashes because of some un handled exception. i have implemented following things

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            handelUnCoughtException(t,e);
        }
    });
}


private void handelUnCoughtException(Thread t , Throwable e){
    Toast.makeText(this , "Handeling Error" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent serviceintent = new Intent(this , ErrorHandelingService.class);
    startService(serviceintent);
}
```

}

above is my application class where i have set default setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler but i am not able to start my service where i have code to start activity please help.

Comment: It's better to implement `crashlytics` android for generate crash report on you register mail id.

Comment: i want to acknowledge user by showing him an custom error activity with a message that this is some technical issue instead of showing him 'application stopped working' popup or abruptly closing application.

Comment: No any idea about this task.
If you got answer then let me know.

Comment: I *strongly* recommend that you use some existing code for this. The VM is in an unknown state when your uncaught exception handler is invoked, and it is not safe for you to do too much here. You might consider integrating [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) and either using [an existing user interaction](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Interactions) or [developing a custom interaction](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Custom-Extensions).

Comment: @HardikParmar please check below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote following class for uncaught exception

public class UncaughtExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

```
private Context context;
private Class<? extends AppCompatActivity> erroractivity;

public UncaughtExceptionHandler(Context context, Class<? extends AppCompatActivity> erroractivity) {
    this.context = context;
    this.erroractivity = erroractivity;
}

public static void setUpErrorHandlingActivity(Context context, Class<? extends AppCompatActivity> erroractivity) {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler(context, erroractivity));
}


@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
    new SystemLog().writeAppRecLog("UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION", "UnCaught Exception.", (Exception) throwable);
    Intent errorActivityIntent = new Intent(context, erroractivity);
    errorActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    errorActivityIntent.setAction("FROM_ERROR_ACTIVITY");
    context.startActivity(errorActivityIntent);
    Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
    System.exit(10);
}
```

}

and in my activity I have registered this class so I can launch my own error activity

```
        UncaughtExceptionHandler.setUpErrorHandlingActivity(getActivityContext(), ErrorActivity.class);
```